# Belkin C300 keyboard not typing anything while booting

Tags: keyboard

While booting using the BELKIN C300 keyboard,power LED on keyboard has power,but no key press works.

But on using another keyboard while booting everything works fine.After booting when I reconnect this same BELKIN C300 keyboard,then I can type everything using the same BELKIN C300 keyboard.need help to solve this one.

totally stumped by this one.Actually bought this BELKIN one as the only other option was a microsoft keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

I have this problem with my Kinesis Advantage. It's a BIOS/UEFI problem; talk to your manufacturer.

Comment: Uh, yes it does answer the question. His keyboard troubles have nothing to do with Ubuntu or any other operating system. The problem is that his BIOS does not recognize the keyboard. The only thing you can do in such a situation is ask the motherboard manufacturer to fix the problem in a new driver.

Comment: fwiw the user asking the question e-mailed me after reading my response, and I helped him further privately. I take it he does not understand the point of these sites as I did not get any upvotes out of the deal, but whatever.